# How do I reference specific cells on Google Sheets in a script? (Preferably when I'm offline)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'd like to run a Google script that references specific cells on separate sheets (same project, different pages). Ideally, I would like to set a time trigger to run this while I'm offline.

I have used the active spreadsheet() function but since I want to reference multiple sheets that doesn't cover all my cases. (Again I'd like this to run while offline so I don't know if active sheet is the answer at all).

Answer (score 0):

The `getActiveSpreadsheet()` <sup>[1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivespreadsheet)</sup> function returns a [Spreadsheet Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet). From this Spreadsheet object you can get all of the sheets that exists within that spreadsheet.

If you mean that you want to **access other spreadsheets**, you can use the .getSpreadsheetById()<sup>[2](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String))</sup>, which also returns a Spreadsheet object that you can use.

*To clarify*, a [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) can contain multiple [Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) (the individual tabs in a Spreadsheet).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can access any sheets in the active spreadsheet, then reference cells from each as necessary. Would look basically something like this (fixed for tehhowch's point in comments):

```
function example() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 1'); 
var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 2');
var sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 3');
var sheet1value = sheet1.getRange('A1').getValue(); 
var sheet2value = sheet2.getRange('A1').getValue(); 
var sheet3value = sheet3.getRange('A1').getValue();
```

Edit: In answer to your question about running offline, getActiveSpreadsheet doesn't require the user to be online; a timed trigger will work fine.

Comment: It is a **terrible** idea to use `setActiveSheet` except in the explicit use cases of *moving* a sheet, or *displaying* a specific sheet to the requesting user. `Spreadsheet#getSheetByName` is the preferred method to obtain a reference to a `Sheet` in the associated workbook.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I'll use that moving forward.